# CameraX throws exception (The completer object was garbage collected this future would otherwise never complete) and Camera is closed

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-camerax

i am facing this issue in Android. Calling `takepictureCameraX()` function from onPasswordFailed override function of DeviceAdminReceiver

```
private fun takepictureCameraX() {

    val camerax = CameraX()`enter code here`
    camerax.startCamera()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        delay(100)
        camerax.takePhoto()
    }

}
inner class  CameraX  :  AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var cameraProviderFuture: ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>
    private lateinit var cameraSelector: CameraSelector
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private lateinit var imgCaptureExecutor: ExecutorService



    fun startCamera() {

        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context!!)
        cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        imgCaptureExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()


        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()

            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, imageCapture)
                Log.d("sdjksdsd", "CameraOpened")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("sdjksdsd", "Use case binding failed")
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context!!))
    }

    fun takePhoto() {
        imageCapture?.let {
           val dir = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/FLP-Intruder/"
            val imageFile = File(dir)
            if (!imageFile.exists()) {
                imageFile.mkdirs()
            }
            val fileName = "JPEG_${System.currentTimeMillis()}" +"Track.png/"
            val file = File(dir, fileName)
            Log.d("sjdshdsdsjkf", "takePhoto: ")
            val outputFileOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file).build()
            it.takePicture(
                outputFileOptions,
                imgCaptureExecutor,
                object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                    override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                        Log.i("sdjksdsd", "The image has been saved in ${file.toUri()}")
                    }

                    override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {

                        Log.d("sdjksdsd", "Error taking photo:${exception.message}")
                    }

                })
        }
    }
}
```